# How to use VIM visualblock to incrementally increase numbers in a block

Tags: vim

I wish to reorder the records in this long file in the column of 3 digits after the ATOM record to start at '1' rather than '534'. Each line represents an atom in a large protein file. I can select the block of text with visual block (ctrl+v) but not sure what to next. I've searched similar problem but the suggested code doesn't work.

I'm using VIM editor and not too familiar with coding I'm afraid.

Eg. Someone suggested selecting the block then use ":I" (didn't work). Other suggestion: select block then use "ctrl+a" (didn't work). Would anyone have the correct VIM method by any chance? 
Many thanks

ATOM    534  C   ACE A   0      10.207  22.900 174.325  1.00 0.00          C

ATOM    535  O   ACE A   0      10.093  22.142 173.352  1.00 0.00          O

ATOM    536  CA  ACE A   0      11.342  22.737 175.312  1.00 0.00          C

ATOM           1  N   PRO A   1       9.225  23.976 174.522  1.00 32.27         N

ATOM           2  CA  PRO A   1       8.230  23.902 173.411  1.00 32.77         C

ATOM           3  C   PRO A   1       8.827  23.261 172.170  1.00 30.28         C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To substitute with an increasing number, we can use a register as the counter; as `setreg()` returns 0 on success, we can invoke it purely for its side effects in the expression, as part of [`:help sub-replace-expression`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression).

```
:let @a = 1 | %s/^ATOM \+\zs\d\+/\=@a + setreg('a', @a + 1)/g
```

The pattern asserts (with [`:help /\zs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs)) that there's the `ATOM` before the number, to avoid other matches.

#### Fixed-width Variant

If you want to keep identical width despite the changing numbers, the following changes need to be done:

1. match the whole field, including leading whitespace
2. use [`:help printf()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#printf%28%29) for a right-aligned fixed-width formatting of the number (`%3d`)

```
:let @a = 1 | %s/^ATOM \zs\s*\d\+/\=printf('%3d', @a + setreg('a', @a + 1))/g
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your time and effort is very much appreciated. I'll give it a go.

Comment: That worked like a dream. Many thanks for your time.  I have another one that's even harder. After every ATOM   record line there's another starting with ANISOU which has to have the same number as the preceeding ATOM record line. I'm imaging this may be nigh impossible with this type of command. My elementary idea would be to temporarily remove all the ANISOU lines into a separate file and apply the same :let command as above for the ATOM lines. But how to reincorporate them back into the right place! Or maybe this complexity requires a script. Many thanks again.

Comment: Ah, nice! If that's the best answer for your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it. If you have a follow-up question (and yours is far more than a simple variation of the original question), please post that separately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do.

Given this text file:

```
$ cat file
Eg. Someone suggested selecting the block then use ":I" (didn't work). Other suggestion: select block then use "ctrl+a" (didn't work). Would anyone have the correct VIM method by any chance? Many thanks
ATOM 534 C ACE A 0 10.207 22.900 174.325 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM 535 O ACE A 0 10.093 22.142 173.352 1.00 0.00 O
ATOM 536 CA ACE A 0 11.342 22.737 175.312 1.00 0.00 C
ATOM      1 N PRO A 1 9.225 23.976 174.522 1.00 32.27 N
ATOM      2 CA PRO A 1 8.230 23.902 173.411 1.00 32.77 C
ATOM      3 C PRO A 1 8.827 23.261 172.170 1.00 30.28 C

Hi there just more stuff in the file.
```

Open the file in vim …

[image]

Now type

```
:2,7!sort -k2 -n
```

Hit enter and you should see …

[image]

Then just `:wq` and you're good to go!

Comment: Hi there thanks so much for the reply. The problem with a 'sort' is that it will change the position of each line so I cant do that. I need to keep each line where it is and just change just those column of numbers. Maybe it's not possible in VIM. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, the 3 digit column of numbers has to be right justified. These text files have very specific criteria for each column for interpretation by the molecular viewer program. For example, the 1st 6 positions are for 'ATOM' records.  The column of numbers I'm referring to tell the viewer about the number of atoms in the system. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, so I found I may need a VIM plugin called "VisIncr" (https://github.com/vim-scripts/VisIncr).   I just need to find out how to install that!. Then I supposedly can select text with ctrl+v then do :II (which shoud increment and right justify numbers in the vertically selected block. I'll try that.

Comment: If that is the case there is probably an `awk` command one could use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Ctrl-v ..........................Select the block with the numbers
:'<,'>s/\d+/1 ...................Substitute all numbers by 1
gv ..............................Repeat the selection
o ...............................jump to the beginning of the selection
j ...............................goes to the seccond line 
g Ctrl-a.........................increase the numbers
```

OBS: If you already have selected the range once use `gv` to reselect and then follow with the substitution then reselect and use `g Ctrl-a`. See more on the help system `:h g_Ctrl-a`

I using `j` for not increase the first number

If something gets wrong just type:

```
:e!
```

this gets your buffer at the point it was when you opened it.

Comment: Hi I tried this set of commands in vim. But the 2nd line where it is supposed to substitute all numbers to 1 returned not finding the string. I'm sure I typed it in as you had it there. Is something missing? Was I supposed to add something else in there? Many thanks again,